# Vimeo not showing on iPad JQuery

Tags: jquery, iframe, vimeo

I have a div that shows after a button is pressed.

```
#popupteaserwidevideo {
    display:none;
        background-color: #000;
    position:absolute;
    float:left;
    width:640px;
    height:360px;
    margin-left: 160px;
    margin-top: 30px;
    z-index: 5;
    border:0px;
}
```

Inside this div is the vimeo iFrame

```
<div id="popupteaserwidevideo"><iframe src="http://player.vimeo.com/video/27620891?byline=0&amp;portrait=0&amp;autoplay=1" width="640" height="360" frameborder="0"></iframe></div>
```

The document.ready code to show or hide the div

```
$(".highlightbutton"), $("#teaser").click(function() {
   $("#popupbackground").fadeToggle('slow');   
   $("#popupteaserwidevideo").fadeToggle('slow'); 

});


$("#popupbackground").click(function() {
   $("#popupbackground").fadeToggle('fast', 0);   
   $("#popupteaserwidevideo").fadeToggle('fast', 0);   
});
```

This all works just great on all browsers I checked. But on the iPad or iPhone, the div does not show the vimeo video. The sound starts playing sometimes though. 
I'm not the greatest programmer around. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you,
Mark

The test file is on [heerlijkhoorspel.be/testtt/](http://www.heerlijkhoorspel.be/testtt)

Answer (score 0):

That's because Flash isn't supported on iOS (iPad/iPhone etc).
Vimeo very recently released a universal player that does support iOS, according to this [Gizmodo story](http://gizmodo.com/5614715/watch-vimeo-videos-on-ipad-using-new-html5-universal-player) and this [Vimeo blog post](http://vimeo.com/blog:334). You will, however have to change your embed code.